# What is the blockToLive property in implicit private data collection in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

In my chaincode I am writing data in multiple implicit private collections (e.g. _implicit_org_Org1MSP), but I couldn't find any information about the default `blockToLive` value used in the implicit collections.

My intent is to keep the data forever, so I would need `blockToLive` set to `0`.

Is this the default? Otherwise is it possible to set a value valid for all the implicit private collections?

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default blockToLive value is 0 for all implicit private data collections.

Answer (score 0):

For implicit private data collection, `blockToLive` is 0, which means data will never purge automatically.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html#implicit-private-data-collections